Several `/dev/uioX` devices fail to enumerate for uio_pdrv_genirq driver
I use the uio_pdrv_genirq driver to control a number of FPGA modules on a Xilinx MPSoC system. I've used this for several months with quite a few FPGA modules (~170) and never had any difficulties until now. Currently, however, I'm running into an issue in which a number of UIO devices fail to enumerate under /dev (and are also not visible under /sys/class/uio). Note that I set compatible = "generic-uio" in the device tree and set uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio as a bootarg.
If I check the number of UIO devices in the running device tree, I see:
$ sudo dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree | grep generic-uio | wc -l
171

But, if I check the number under /dev, I see:
$ ls /dev/uio* | wc -l
158

I don't see anything in dmesg that indicates a failing enumeration.
The devices which do not enumerate are some Xilinx AXI DMA cores. However, the UIO devices for these enumerated just fine in a previous version of the design. The only change I made, relevant to these cores, is to connect their interrupt outputs to a Xilinx AXI interrupt controller (which I've also made a generic-uio device).
Here's an example AXI DMA core configuration in the device tree:
dma@80000000 {
        xlnx,include-sg;
        clock-names = "s_axi_lite_aclk", "m_axi_sg_aclk", "m_axi_s2mm_aclk";
        interrupts = <0x0 0x2>;
        clocks = <0x3 0x48 0x3 0x47 0x3 0x49>;
        interrupt-parent = <0x30>;
        xlnx,addrwidth = <0x20>;
        compatible = "generic-uio";
        interrupt-names = "s2mm_introut";
        xlnx,sg-length-width = <0x1a>;
        reg = <0x0 0x80000000 0x0 0x10000>;
        phandle = <0xa6>;
        #dma-cells = <0x1>;

        dma-channel@80000030 {
                xlnx,device-id = <0x0>;
                interrupts = <0x0 0x2>;
                compatible = "xlnx,axi-dma-s2mm-channel";
                dma-channels = <0x1>;
                xlnx,datawidth = <0x80>;
        };
};

In that previous version of the design I see more devices under /dev:
$ ls /dev/uio* | wc -l
174

Any idea what might be happening here? How can I troubleshoot these devices not showing up under /dev?
Please let me know if you need further information and I'd be happy to provide it.

I managed to get this working by deleting the interrupts property of the AXI DMA core instances with /delete-property/ interrupts;. Since I use the uio_pdrv_genirq driver to manage the AXI interrupt controller, I used its UIO instance (along with my driver for it) to handle interrupts from the AXI DMA cores.
I believe the underlying issue here is that the AXI DMA core interrupts were connected to the AXI interrupt controller and not to the processor directly, causing the driver not to be able to manage these interrupts. The uio_pdrv_genirq driver can, however, manage devices without interrupts if they do not have an interrupts property. But, of course, when this is the case you cannot read from and write to the /dev/uioX instance to await and enable interrupts.
